# How to display data from database into a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

guy's i am trying to make my database showing into my checkbox (multi select).
but i dont know how.
i tried to make a code but it didn't work. here is my code.
i hope someone can help me with this and give me an example for the jquery code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"../php/absen/absen_karyawan_autocomplete.php",
  success: function(data){
   var list = JSON.parse(data);
   for(var i=0; i < list.length; i++){
   $("#multiselect").append($("<label>").text((list[i]['nama'])).prepend(
        $("<input>").attr('type', 'checkbox').val((list[i]['nama'])).prop('checked', true)
        ));
   }
   return false;
  }
 });
});
```

```css
.multiselect {
    width:20em;
    height:10em;
    border:solid 1px #c0c0c0;
    overflow:auto;
}
 
.multiselect label {
    display:block;
}
 
.multiselect-on {
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#000099;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="multiselect">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="1" />I want put my database data here </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="2" />Red</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="3" />Blue</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="4" />Orange</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="5" />Purple</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="6" />Black</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="7" />White</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="1" />Green</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="2" />Red</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="3" />Blue</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="4" />Orange</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="5" />Purple</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="6" />Black</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="7" />White</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="1" />Green</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="2" />Red</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="3" />Blue</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="4" />Orange</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="5" />Purple</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="6" />Black</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="7" />White</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="1" />Green</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="2" />Red</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="3" />Blue</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="4" />Orange</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="5" />Purple</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="6" />Black</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="7" />White</label>
</div>
```

I have try to make an example for what i need 
i just use one json data.
i hope someone can help me to change my code to server side .
i have made the code for server side like the 1st question but i am fail and the data not displaying at my page

```js
var json = [
  {
    name: "I want to displaying my database data like this",
    id: "27",
    checked: "true"
    
  }
  
 
];

$.each(json, function () {
        $("#multiselect").append($("<label>").text(this.name).prepend(
            $("<input>").attr('type', 'checkbox').val(this.id)
               .prop('checked', this.checked)
        ));
    });


    $("#multiselect").on('change', '[type=checkbox]', function () {
       console.log($(this).val());
    });
```

```css
.multiselect {
    width:20em;
    height:10em;
    border:solid 1px #c0c0c0;
    overflow:auto;
}
 
.multiselect label {
    display:block;
}
 
.multiselect-on {
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#000099;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="multiselect"></div>
```

Comment: what does not work? what error do you get?

Comment: wheats in the php/absen/absen_karyawan_autocomplete.php ?

Comment: You have syntax error, it should be `.text(list[i]['nama'])` and also `this.checked`, Whats is `this`?

Comment: @AMB that's my database

Comment: @Satpal oh.. i try to change it thx..

Comment: @MinervazMine that's no database.

Comment: @PhilippSander sorry I mean my php function for call my database.
im not putting that. do i need to put that?

Comment: @MinervazMine you could add a sample response to the question, that might help.